# Should we NULL every raw pointer after it is used?

Tags: c++, pointers, unique-ptr

```cpp
int *a;
if (true)
    *a = 2;
else
    *a = 3;
```

As you see, `a` is not a dynamically allocated pointer. Should I assign it to `nullptr` before exiting? Does `unique_ptr` do for me automatically? What about the memory pointer to by `a`? If I null `a` before it goes out of scope, will it cause a memory leak?

Comment: That code is UB, `a` isn't pointing at anything.

Comment: What goals do you want to achieve? In what way does your proposed change affect the goal? Why would you use `unique_ptr`? Does that relate to your goals? How do memory leaks happen? These are all more or less separate questions which you can research independently. Most of those are FAQs though, so start with that.

Comment: Your code doesn't require your comipler to translate this into anything that works(Undefined behaviour). Assigning `nullptr` to a pointer may make sense in some scenarios ***after using the `delete` operator*** to allow the compiler to warn you about accidentally accessing a deleted object in some scenarios, or at least make the code crash instead of not knowing anything about the effects of the memory access, but `std::unique_ptr` does not "help" with anything related; `std::unique_ptr` just makes the ownership clear and ensures the `delete` operator is called on the object it owns...

Comment: Btw: Memory leak, even though set to null: `void f() { int* p = new int; p = nullptr; }` No memory leak even though not set to null: `void f() { int* p = new int; delete p; }`

Comment: *What about the memory pointer to by `a`?*  Since `a` is **uninitialized**, it doesn't point to an `int`.  Your compiler should have warned you about that.  Turn on your compiler warnings.  Fix the warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> int *a;
> if (true)
>     *a = 2;
> ```

The behaviour of this program is undefined. `a` does not have a valid pointer value, so you may not indirect through.

> Should we NULL every raw pointer after it is used?

It depends. For example, if the lifetime of the pointer is about to end, then it's redundant to assign it to null.

> Does unique_ptr do for me automatically?

unique_ptr isn't a raw pointer.

But no, unique_ptr cannot know whether you've stopped using it or not, so it cannot set itself to null when you've stopped using it.

> If I null a before it goes out of scope, will it cause a memory leak?

There is no difference between setting a pointer null, and not setting it to null before the pointer goes out of scope.